# Select all column excepting one in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query :

```
select * 
from tab a 
inner join tab2 b on a.id = b.id
```

I have 20 columns, but I want to exclude one.

Do you have any performant way to do it please?

I know that I can use it when I have all data in one table but I want to it in this query.

Comment: The **only** way to do this (and the **recommended** way, too), is to **explicitly list** all those columns that you *want to select* and want to include in your result set

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the name of the columns? You could do

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 FROM tab a inner join tab2 b on a=id=b.id
```

Comment: If i do it manually , i will have 20 columns to write. I want to avoid this way

Comment: This is the only way to achieve this, why do you not want to type out 20 columns one time?